# Intento instalar PyQt5-tools pero me arroja este error metadata-generation-failed

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5

He intentado instalar PyQt5-tools pero me arroja el error "Metadata-generation-filed" y lo quiero usar para realizar mi primera GUI
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Antes que nada, ¡Bienvenido a SOes!. Vendría mejor que especifiques más tu pregunta mostrando el código de tu problema y lo que estás intentado resolver a más detalle. Te recomiendo que visites el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y mires [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, ¡Saludos!.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.